# What WebRTC constraints and options should i pass to get interoperability between Firefox and Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I'm building a chat application for a LAN. I use WebRTC but can't get Firefox and Google chrome to interoperate.
I don't know the exact parameters i should pass to RTCPeerConnection createOffer/createAnswer.

I made the tests below with **Firefox 31** and **Google Chrome 36** in the same computer Fedora Linux 20

RTCPeerConnection is created like:
    `pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null, RTC_PC_OPTIONS);`

answers/offers are created like:
    `pc.createOffer(onsuccess, onfail, CONSTRAINTS);`

My question is: which parameters (`RTC_PC_OPTIONS` and `CONSTRAINTS`) should i pass to get interoperability between the two browsers?

## Test 1

```
RTC_PC_OPTIONS = undefined
CONSTRAINTS = undefined

                        FFx2FFx     FFx2Chrome      Chrome2FFx      Chrome2Chrome
                        -------     ----------      ----------      -------------
dataChannel setup       ok          ok              ok              ok
dataChannel send/recv   ok          ok              ok              ok
Video stream            ok          ok              err [1]         ok
```

## Test 2

```
MDN recomands this value for RTC_PC_OPTIONS

RTC_PC_OPTIONS = {
    optional: [
        {DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement: true},
        {RtpDataChannels: true}
    ]
};
CONSTRAINTS = undefined

                        FFx2FFx     FFx2Chrome      Chrome2FFx      Chrome2Chrome
                        -------     ----------      ----------      -------------
dataChannel setup       ok          err [2]         err [3]         ok
dataChannel send/recv   ok          -               -               ok
Video stream            ok          -               -               err [4]
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ 
                                            ^
                   i used datachannel to do signaling for the video TRCPeerConnection,
                   that is why these were not tested
```

## Test 3

```
RTC_PC_OPTIONS = undefined
CONSTRAINTS = { 'mandatory': { 'OfferToReceiveAudio': true, 'OfferToReceiveVideo': true } }

                        FFx2FFx     FFx2Chrome      Chrome2FFx      Chrome2Chrome
                        -------     ----------      ----------      -------------
dataChannel setup       ok          ok              ok              err [5]
dataChannel send/recv   ok          ok              ok              -
Video stream            err [6]     ok              err [6]         -
```

---

1. Chrome creates offer and sends it to FFx, FFx receives offer, creates answer and sends it to chrome,

chrome receives the answer. But onaddstream is not triggred in firefox

---

2. After chrome receives the offer sent by FFx, it logs an error to the console:

`Failed to set remote offer sdp: Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to set data send codecs..`

---

3. Chrome sends the offer, FFx sends the answer,

chrome gets this error: `Failed to parse SessionDescription. m=application 35224 RTP/SAVPF Expects at least 4 fields.`

FFx gets this error: `ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details`

In `about:webrtc`:

`Local candidate                Remote candidate            ICE State   Priority            Nominated   Selected
a.b.c.d:35224/udp(host)     a.b.c.d:45895/udp(host)     frozen      9115005270282354000`

---

4. Chrome_1 gets the error: `Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': Could not send data`

chrome_2 gets the error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The ICE candidate could not be added.`

---

5. The caller sends the offer, the callee gets an error:

`Failed to set remote offer sdp: Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to set data send codecs.`

---

6. Like [1] everything ok but onaddstream not triggered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, a few things:

1. Whatever MDN page suggests RTPDataChannels is very outdated (let me know the URL).  Both Firefox and Chrome support spec DataChannels now.  Same for DTLSSRTPKeyAgreement I believe
2. Make sure you call createDataChannel() before createOffer()
3. Is it video-only, or video+audio?  We fixed a bug with video-only streams recently if I recall not triggering onAddStream.  That would explain [1](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1035067) and [6] I think.  See [bug 1035067](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1035067), which is landed in Nightly and Aurora (FF33); I've asked for uplift to Beta/32
4. The "expects 4 fields" issue if I recall was bug in Firefox - what versions are you running?  We did have a bug fixed in 30(?) where we had an unneeded space on the end which caused chrome to reject it - they patched to avoid it, and we fixed it.

Try it with FF Beta, and Nightly (http://nightly.mozilla.org/).  And when you report things like this, please indicate what versions of browser you're using! :-)

Comment: thank you so match @jesup,

1) here is [the mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC/WebRTC_basics) (last edited Mar 8).

2) yes i do.

3) it is video only and one way (only one peer transmits video).

4) I have mentioned that the versions are FFX 31.0 and Chrome 36. I should have written it in bold :-)

I will try it with nightly and see

Comment: I have just tested with Firefox nightly and everything work with `RTC_PC_OPTIONS = undefined` and `CONSTRAINTS = undefined`. Thanks again!